# How can I store variable length codes sequentially in memory?

Tags: c, arrays, embedded

Say I have a two dimensional array where each entry contains a length and a value:

```
int array[4][2] =  { /* {length, value}, */
                   {5, 3},
                   {6, 7},
                   {1, 0},
                   {8, 15},
                   };
```

I want to store them sequentially into memory with leading zeros to make each field the appropriate length.  The example above would be:

```
    00011 000111 0 00001111
```

The first block is five bits long and stores decimal 3.  The second block is six bits long and stores decimal seven.  The third block is one bit long and stores decimal 0, and the last block is eight bits long and stores decimal 15.

I can do it with some bitwise manipulation but I thought I would ask to see if there is an easier way.

I am coding in C for a Tensilica 32-bit RISC processor.

The purpose is to write a sequence of Exponential-Golomb codes.

EDIT: SOLUTION:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0;
    unsigned char bit = 0;
    unsigned int bit_num = 0;
    unsigned int field_length_bits = 0;
    unsigned int field_length_bytes = 0;
    unsigned int field_array_length = 0;
    unsigned int field_list[NUM_FIELDS][2] = {
                                            /*{Length, Value},*/ 
                                            {4,  3},
                                            {5,  5},
                                            {6,  9},
                                            {7,  11},
                                            {8,  13},
                                            {9, 15},
                                            {10, 17},
                                         };

    unsigned char *seq_array;

    // Find total length of field list in bits
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_FIELDS; i++) 
        field_length_bits += field_list[i][LENGTH];

    // Number of bytes needed to store FIELD parameters
    for (i = 0; i < (field_length_bits + i) % 8 != 0; i++) ;

    field_length_bytes = (field_length_bits + i) / 8;

    // Size of array we need to allocate (multiple of 4 bytes)
    for (i = 0; (field_length_bytes + i) % 4 != 0; i++) ;

    field_array_length = (field_length_bytes + i);

    // Allocate memory
    seq_array = (unsigned char *) calloc(field_array_length, sizeof(unsigned char));

    // Traverse source and set destination
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_FIELDS; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < field_list[i][LENGTH]; j++)
        {
            bit = 0x01 & (field_list[i][VALUE] >> (field_list[i][LENGTH] - j - 1));
            if (bit)
                setBit(seq_array, field_array_length, bit_num, 1);
            else
                setBit(seq_array, field_array_length, bit_num, 0);
            bit_num++;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}



void setBit(unsigned char *array, unsigned int array_len, unsigned int bit_num, unsigned int bit_value)
{
    unsigned int byte_location = 0;
    unsigned int bit_location = 0;

    byte_location = bit_num / 8;
    if(byte_location > array_len - 1)
    {
        printf("setBit(): Unauthorized memory access");
        return;
    }
    bit_location = bit_num % 8;

    if(bit_value)
        array[byte_location] |= (1 << (7-bit_location));
    else
        array[byte_location] &= ~(1 << (7-bit_location)); 

    return;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a *string* of numbers formatted as a textual, binary representation with digits `0` and `1`?

Comment: You can try encoding this into a sequence of chars, but honestly, I can't think of a reason why you'd want to do this.

Comment: do you really care about space that much that you need to pack them together smaller than a char?  If not, then make your entry hold {number_of_chars, value}, so it would be {1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 0}, {1, 15}, {2, 345} // I added the last one for an example

Comment: Notice the tags c and embedded. He is probably using it to transmit compressed data.

Comment: The only sane _and_ easy way to do this in an embedded application is as an array of bytes, which is accessed with bitwise operators. Bit-field behavior has horribly poor support by the standard, so they should not be used. "Bit streams" (whatever that is), seems to be la-la-land... why turn something as simple and quick as this into something needlessly complicated and extremely slow?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a bitstream library:

## **Highly recommended bitstream library:**

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KURIHARA/Imager-QRCode-0.033/src/bitstream.c

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/KURIHARA/Imager-QRCode-0.033/src/bitstream.h

Because this bitstream library seems to be very self-contained, and doesn't seem to require external includes.

---

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32783/CBitStream-A-simple-C-class-for-reading-and-writin - C library, but using windows WORD, DWORD types (you can still typedef to use this library)

http://code.google.com/p/youtube-mobile-ffmpeg/source/browse/trunk/libavcodec/bitstream.c?r=8 - includes quite a few other include files to use the bitstream library

---

If you just want exponential golomb codes, there are open-source C implementations:

http://www.koders.com/c/fid8A317DF502A7D61CC96EC4DA07021850B6AD97ED.aspx?s=gcd

---

Or you can use bit manipulation techniques.

For example:

```
unsigned int array[4][2] = ???
unsigned int mem[100] = {};
int index=0,bit=0;
for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
  int shift = (32 - array[i][0] - bit);
  if (shift>0) mem[index] &= array[i][1] << shift;
  else {
    mem[index] &= array[i][1] >> -shift;
    mem[index+1] &= array[i][1] << (32+shift);
  }

  bit += array[i][1];

  if (bit>=32) {
    bit-=32;
    index++;
  }
}
```

Disclaimer:

The code only works if your computer byte-order is little endian, and the result will actually be little-endian within each 4-byte boundary, and big-endian across 4-byte boundaries. If you convert mem from int type to char, and replace the constants 32 to 8, you will get a big-endian representation of your bit-array.

It also assumes that the length is less than 32. Obviously, the code you actually want will depend on the bounds of valid input, and what you want in terms of byte-ordering.

Comment: Shifting a 1 into or past the sign bit is technically *undefined behavior* in current C/C++ standards.  Use unsigned types to be safe.  Also, you make the assumption that `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT == 32`... probably true.  (Nitpicks, both.  Upvoted anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like a *bit field*?

```
struct myBF
{
    unsigned int v1 : 5;
    unsigned int v2 : 5;
    unsigned int v3 : 1;
    unsigned int v4 : 8;
};

struct myBF b = { 3, 7, 0, 15 };
```

I may be misunderstanding your requirements entirely. Please comment if that's the case.

---

*Update:* Suppose you want to do this *dynamically*. Let's make a function that accepts an array of pairs, like in your example, and an output buffer:

```
/* Fill dst with bits.
 * Returns one plus the number of bytes used or 0 on error.
 */
size_t bitstream(int (*arr)[2], size_t arrlen,
                          unsigned char * dst, size_t dstlen)
{
    size_t total_bits = 0, bits_so_far = 0;

    /* Check if there's enough space */
    for (size_t i = 0; i != arrlen; ++i) { total_bits += arr[i][0]; }
    if (dst == NULL || total_bits > CHAR_BIT * dstlen)  { return 0; }

    /* Set the output range to all zero */
    memset(dst, 0, dstlen);

    /* Populate the output range */
    for (size_t i = 0; i != arrlen; ++i)
    {
        for (size_t bits_to_spend = arr[i][0], value = arr[i][1];
             bits_to_spend != 0; /* no increment */ )
        {
            size_t const bit_offset = bits_so_far % CHAR_BIT;
            size_t const byte_index = bits_so_far / CHAR_BIT;
            size_t const cur_byte_capacity = CHAR_BIT - bit_offset;

            /* Debug: Watch it work! */
            printf("Need to store %zu, %zu bits to spend, capacity %zu.\n",
                   value, bits_to_spend, cur_byte_capacity);

            dst[byte_index] |= (value << bit_offset);

            if (cur_byte_capacity < bits_to_spend)
            {
                value        >>= cur_byte_capacity;
                bits_so_far   += cur_byte_capacity;
                bits_to_spend -= cur_byte_capacity;
            }
            else
            {
                bits_so_far += bits_to_spend;
                bits_to_spend = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return (bits_so_far + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT;
}
```

Notes:

- If the number `arr[i][1]` does not fit into `arr[i][0]` bits, only the residue modulo 2<sup>`arr[i][0]`</sup> is stored.
- To be perfectly correct, the array type should be unsigned as well, otherwise the initialization `size_t value = arr[i][1]` may be undefined behaviour.
- You can modify the error handling behaviour. For example, you could forgo transactionality and move the length check into the main loop. Also, instead of returning `0`, you could return the num­ber of *required* bytes, so that the user can figure out how big the destination array needs to be (like `snptrintf` does).

Usage:

```
unsigned char dst[N];
size_t n = bitstream(array, sizeof array / sizeof *array, dst, sizeof dst);
for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) { printf("0x%02X ", dst[n - i - 1]); }
```

For your example, this will produce `0x00 0xF0 0xE3`, which is:

```
  0x00     0xF0     0xE3
00000000 11110000 11100011

0000 00001111 0 000111 00011
padd    15    0    7     3
```

Comment: This should work as long as you know the lengths at compile time.

Comment: Yes, like a bit field, but I won't know at compile-time what the values and lengths will be (only how many values). Is that possible?

Comment: @CharleyAbboud: Not to my knowledge. You'll have to write your own wrapper and handler. How will you recover the number of bits in each field anyway?

Comment: Essentially, I am trying write a sequence of Exponential-Golomb codes, so I don't need to worry about recovering the field lengths.

Comment: @CharleyAbboud: I see. I think you'll need to write your own code for that. Let me see if I can contrive something.

Comment: @CharleyAbboud: Done. Have a look at my `bitstream` algorithm.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that isn't called a bitstream algorithm. A stream is something you can add/push stuff onto arbitrarily - not all at the same time.

Comment: @ronalchn: I suppose that my algorithm can be modified with a few steps to act on a persistent state...

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I worked on a solution independently and ended up with something similar but not as elegant.

Answer (score 0):

In standard C there's no way to access anything smaller than a `char` by any way other than the 'bitwise manipulation` you mention.  I'm afraid you're out of luck, unless you come across a library somewhere out there that can help you.